# Google play developer API - Voided Purchases API response 403

Tags: android-inapp-purchase

I want to ask a question about IAB API - Voided Purchases API https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/voidedpurchases/list
response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "androidpublisher",
                "message": "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation.",
                "reason": "forbidden"
            }
        ],
        "message": "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation."
    }
}
```

---

Please get me some suggestion about using this API. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's late but may help someone else

I think you pass the wrong [query parameters](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.voidedpurchases/list#query-parameters) to API.

a most common mistake is about timestamps for `startTime` and `endTime`
as the documents say :

> The time, in milliseconds since the [Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

check that your timestamp is in milliseconds and not seconds

Comment: Thank you! I was probably confused when I made my first draft of this service and thought I would give the startTime in "number of days back" for some reason. The error response I received made me look for the solution in the wrong place until I found this!